# hgsubversion can't find repository

Tags: svn, ubuntu, mercurial, hgsubversion

So, we have svn repository of our project. Previously I stored the copy of this project in local hg repository via hgsubversion extension, and everything worked just fine.
Today I reinstalled ubuntu, and switched from 12.04 to 13.04. I've installed **hg** (version 2.2.2), **subversion** (version 1.7.5) and **hgsubversion** (1.4-1).
I can clone repository via `hg clone`, but after that I can't execute any operation involving cooperation with the remote svn repository - I keep getting the following error:

```
abort: repository svn+https://'our-project-url' not found!
```

What can be a reason of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked this question an year ago, and I don't remember the details, but I remember that the issue was in the incorrect name and/or placement of `hgrc` file which belonged to the repository - I've either named it `.hgrc` and put inside the `project-dir/.hg` directory (`project-dir/.hg/.hgrc`) or put it inside the `project-dir` directory (`project-dir/.hgrc`).
The correct name/placement is, of course `project-dir/.hg/hgrc`.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if the `hgsubversion` extension is not set/enabled in your `hgrc` file.